# Trying to convert an arraylist of integers into primitive type int[]

Tags: java, arraylist, primitive-types

I have an arraylist of Integers called `stockList`.

I want a primitive type of int[] `stockListFinal` to be made form the arrayList.

***Code:***

```
public class Warehouses {

    ArrayList<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<Warehouse>();
    ArrayList<Integer> stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> locationsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int[] stockListFINAL;
    int[] locationsListFINAL;

    public Warehouses() {

        addWarehouses();

        stockList();

        locationList();    
    }

    public void addWarehouses() {
        //DATABASE WOULD BE SEARCHED FOR EACH PRESENT RECORD AND ADDED HERE
        //FOR SIMPLICITY I HAVE DONE THIS MANUALLY

        warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W1", 20, "RM13 8BB"));
        warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W2", 28, "RM13 8BB"));
        warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W3", 17, "RM13 8BB"));
    }

    public void stockList() {

        for(Warehouse warehouse : warehouses) {

            Integer stock = warehouse.getStock();        
        }

        stockListFINAL = convertIntegers(stockList);
    }

    public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];

        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void locationList() {
        for(Warehouse warehouse : warehouses) {

            String location = warehouse.getLocation();
        }
    } 
}


class Warehouse
{
    private String warehouseID;
    private int warehouseStock;
    private String location;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Warehouse
     */
    public Warehouse(String warehouseID, int warehouseStock, String location)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.warehouseID = warehouseID;
        this.warehouseStock = warehouseStock;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getStock(){
        return warehouseStock;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

`stockListFinal` however returns empty.

What has happened here?

Comment: Well, yeah, you haven't called `addStock` yet...

Comment: Sorry typo - addStock is called in the method.

Comment: What method is that?  Maybe you should show the entire class, rather than just snippets.

Comment: Can you show `intValue` method?

Comment: In your latest edit, you have warehouses - you still never set-up a stock list.

Comment: So where do you instantiate your `Warehouses` class?

Comment: In `stockList()` method what is the purpose of `for (Warehouse warehouse : warehouses) {Integer stock = warehouse.getStock();}`? In this code you just read stacks but doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `addStock()` so the List is empty.

```
addStock();                                        // this was missing, and it
                                                   // should probably take the
                                                   // List as an argument.
int[] stockListFINAL = convertIntegers(stockList);
```

I then verified with this code

```
// No change.
public static int[] convertIntegers(
    List<Integer> integers) {
  int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];

  for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
    ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
  }
  return ret;
}

// Made static, added List as argument.
public static void addStock(List<Integer> stockList) {
  stockList.add(20);
  stockList.add(30);
}

public static void main(String s[]) {
  ArrayList<Integer> stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  addStock(stockList);
  int[] stockListFINAL = convertIntegers(stockList);
  System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(stockListFINAL));
}
```

And it outputs -

```
[20, 30]
```

You never added Stock(s) to your List(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you run `main` in the class below you'll see the `int[]` is populated.  This isn't how I'd recommend implementing, but I've tried to remain as close to your example as possible:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SE
{
    final static ArrayList<Integer> stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static int[] convertIntegers(final List<Integer> integers)
    {
        final int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void addStock()
    {
        stockList.add(20);
        stockList.add(30);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        addStock();
        final int[] stockListFINAL = convertIntegers(stockList);
        for (int i = 0; i < stockListFINAL.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format(" For location %d in the int[] the value is %d", i, stockListFINAL[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well now that your code example is completely different, this isn't an exact match.  But it will work for your original code and you can use this as an example to figure out what is wrong with your new code example.